# Power BI unable to read Excel worksheet with multiple tabs

Tags: excel, powerbi, xls

I have an Excel worksheet with 10 tabs.

For each tab, the data is structured as follows:

[image]

All tabs follow this same basic structure.

In Power BI, when I go to "Get Data", and then choose the .xlsx file, I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect

We encountered an error while trying to connect.

Details: "The input couldn't be recognized as a valid Excel document."
```

I don't know how such a simple task cannot be accomplished in Power BI.

Comment: I have solved this.  Power BI does not like files on the network drive, it appears.  This worked once I saved the file to my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Such alert could appear when you try to use Power BI connector on Excel file. It's understandable if the source file is corrupted and can't be opened in Excel. However, it looks strange if Excel opens the file in question and shows nothing wrong.

Based on our experience above is usually means what something is wrong with XML scheme of the Excel workbook.

Mushup trace (Data->New Query->Query Options->Diagnostics->Enable tracing) could give some additional information, but often not enough to find the reason.

We had two main scenarios

XML scheme is not complete
Usually if Excel file was generated by third-party tool. Such tool could generate quite limited XML scheme which is enough to open the file in Excel and to work with it, but not enough for Power BI connector. As an example, trace log shows

[DataFormat.Error] The input couldn't be recognized as a valid Excel document.\r\nStackTrace:\n…
…
[DataFormat.Error] We couldn't find a part named '/xl/sharedStrings.xml' in the Excel package.\r\nStackTrace:\n…
Such case is easy to fix – it's enough to open the file in Excel and save it (without any changes) – Excel is clever enough to fix the scheme. For the routine regular tasks we use poweshell script which does exactly the same in background.

There is the link within Excel file which is not recognizable as valid
Usually if Excel file is synced/kept with some cloud storage. One of the variants, wrong link could appear with copy/paste from another such file. That could be active link in one of the cells; or the link within conditional formatting formula; or even the link which actually isn't used by Excel but kept somewhere inside the scheme. For example, in one of the files I found in Data->Consolidate->All references the link like

'\drive.tresorit.com@7235\Tresors….[file.xlsx]Sheet'!$AC$6:$AC$357
on the file which was deleted long ago and isn't used, but for some strange reason the link was kept within the scheme.

Unfortunately for such case trace log doesn't give enough information to localize the issue, it looks like

[DataFormat.Error] The input couldn't be recognized as a valid Excel document.\r\nStackTrace:\n…
…
nExceptionType: System.UriFormatException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\r\nMessage: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.\r\nStackTrace:\n
Perhaps I have not enough knowledge for more straight forward localization of the problem, but the only way is to exclude Excel file parts one by one and check if the issue disappeared. Another way could be to unzip Excel file and check if wookbook.xml or sheetNN.xml have something suspicious inside.