# Writing .xlsx in R, importing into PowerBi error

Tags: r, excel, powerbi

I'm experiencing an odd error.  I have a large dataframe in R (75000 rows, 97 columns) and I need to save it out and then import it into Power Bi.

At first I just did the simple:

```
library(tidyverse)
write_csv(Visits,"Visits.csv")
```

and while it seems to export and looks fine in excel, the csv itself is all messed up when I look at the contents in Power Bi.  Here's an example of what I mean:

The 'phase.x' column should only have "follow-up" or "treatment" in that column.   In excel, looks great:
[image]

but that exact same file gets screwed up in Power Bi:

[image]

I figured that being a 'comma separated variable' file, there must be some extra comma somewhere, and I saved it as an .xlsx instead.

So, while in excel, I saved that .csv as an .xlsx and it opened great in Power Bi!

Jump forward a moment and instead of write_csv() in R, I use write.xlsx().   But now I get this error:

[image]

If I simply go to that file, open it in excel, save it and hit close, that error goes away and it can load into Power Bi just fine. [I figure it has something to do with this question on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056063/power-bi-unable-to-read-excel-worksheet-with-multiple-tabs).

Any ideas on what I might be screwing up as I save it out of R?  Somehow I can fix it in R and not have to open and save it every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In power BI check that your source has ignore quoted line breaks enabled. I've found this is often an issue with .csv files in PowerBI.
[image]